# sharepoint 2013 installation issue

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have created an Oracle virtual box VM using Windows server 2012 R2 standard OS. Then I installed active directory services using sever manager feature and then I installed SQL server 2012 express edition and installed all prerequisites for SharePoint server 2013. All prerequisites are installed successfully. All the installation done on a single machine. But still I am getting an error while installing SharePoint 2013.

Setup is unable to proceed due to the following error:

> Windows server App-fabric is not correctly configured.You should uninstall Windows Server App-fabric and reinstall it using the SharePoint Product Preparation tool.

Answer (score 0):

The sharepoint install disk has an executable named something like prerequisite.exe. Beware though you need to do your install with SharePoint 2013 SP1. SP1 being the key.